# R ggplot2 add additional x-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the code and data below, is there a way to add `15%` after each `10%` to show that the values are greater/less than or equal to `+/-` `15%` on the `x-axis`?

Please note that one of the datasets does not have `15` in the `Value` column

I tried using `scale_x_discrete` with the `limits` argument, but it doesn't work.

Desired `x-axis` order on both the plots:

```
15% 10% 0 10% 15%
```

Data (`pop_hisp_df`):

```
structure(list(age_group = c("<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", 
"25  -  34", "35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", 
"75  -  84", "85 +", "<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", "25  -  34", 
"35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", "75  -  84", 
"85 +"), Type = c("Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", 
"Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females"), Value = c(-6, -13, -13, -15, -17, -15, 
-11, -6, -3, -1, 6, 12, 12, 14, 16, 15, 12, 7, 4, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`pop_gen_df`:

```
structure(list(age_group = c("<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", 
"25  -  34", "35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", 
"75  -  84", "85 +", "<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", "25  -  34", 
"35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", "75  -  84", 
"85 +"), Type = c("Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", 
"Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females"), Value = c(-6, -12, -12, -14, -13, -14, 
-13, -9, -4, -2, 6, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 13, 10, 5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(plotly)
    
    # Plot
    gg_pop_hisp = ggplot(pop_hisp_df, aes( x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type)) +
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "females"), stat = "identity") + 
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "males"), stat = "identity") + 
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(z) paste0(abs(z), "%")) +          # CHANGE
      scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("females"="#FC921F", "males"="#149ECE"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
      ggtitle("HISPANIC POPULATION BY GENDER AND AGE GROUP") +
      labs(x = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", y = "AGE GROUPS", fill = "Gender") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom") +
      coord_flip()

gg_pop_gen = ggplot(pop_gen_df, aes(x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type))  +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(z) paste0(abs(z), "%")) +          # CHANGE
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Females"="#ED5151", "Males"="#6B6BD6"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
  ggtitle("TOTAL POPULATION BY AGE AND GENDER") +
  labs(x = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", y = "AGE GROUPS", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  coord_flip()
    
    # Interactive and place legend at the bottom
    ggplotly(gg_pop_hisp) %>% 
      layout(
        legend = list(
          orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.1, 
          title = list(text = '')
          )
        )

ggplotly(gg_pop_gen) %>% 
  layout(
    legend = list(
      orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.3, 
      title = list(text = '')
      )
    )
```

Comment: add limits to your scale? `scale_y_continuous(labels = function(z) paste0(abs(z), "%"), limits = c(-20, 20))`

Comment: This gives me an empty plot, but I will try again just to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, your second plot shows up empty. You are mixing both data.frames in that one. Plus something else, that I can't spot so quickly.

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that.. In the second plot, you need to subset with lower case female and males, as well as make sure you are using the right data.frame, and change the names of the `values` vector in `scale_fill_manual()` to lowercase males and females

Comment: @langtang, thank you for pointing that out, I have fixed the data provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `scale_y_continuous` for both plots to :

```
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits=c(-20,20),
    breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
    labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")
  )
```

Full Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# Plot
gg_pop_hisp = ggplot(pop_hisp_df, aes( x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") + 
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = function(z) paste0(abs(z), "%")) +          # CHANGE
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits=c(-20,20),
    breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
    labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")
  ) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Females"="#FC921F", "Males"="#149ECE"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
  ggtitle("HISPANIC POPULATION BY GENDER AND AGE GROUP") +
  labs(x = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", y = "AGE GROUPS", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  coord_flip()

gg_pop_hisp

gg_pop_gen = ggplot(pop_gen_df, aes(x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type))  +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_gen_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_gen_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") + 
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = function(z) paste0(abs(z), "%")) +          # CHANGE
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits=c(-20,20),
    breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
    labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")
  ) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Females"="#ED5151", "Males"="#6B6BD6"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
  ggtitle("TOTAL POPULATION BY AGE AND GENDER") +
  labs(x = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", y = "AGE GROUPS", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  coord_flip()

# Interactive and place legend at the bottom
ggplotly(gg_pop_hisp) %>% 
  layout(
    legend = list(
      orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.1, 
      title = list(text = '')
    )
  )

ggplotly(gg_pop_gen) %>% 
  layout(
    legend = list(
      orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.3, 
      title = list(text = '')
    )
  )
```

Comment: Did it work for you? Because, when I try the above code in `gg_pop_hisp`, I get an empty plot, although the `x-axis` labels are showing as intended. I just added the code to `scale_y_continous`, and removed `labels = function(z) paste0(abs(z), "%")`. No other changes were made to the code. Actually, both of the plots are returning empty.

Comment: Both are working for me.. but I see you changed your data?  Now, it appears as though both of your dataset have capital "Males" and "Females".. so I've added full working code.. When you use `subset` and when you refer to the categories in `scale_fill_manual`, you have to make sure that the strings are exactly as they are in the underlying dataset, including capitalization

Comment: yep, restarting `RStudio` fixed the empty plot issue, cheers.